# How to deact scroll and show component when user scrolled to top in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

**When the user scroll to the top and then scrolls event returns a higher number like - 10 or 20 or 2000 or 300 based on the content and when the user scrolled to the button then it will return 0**

```
  const [scrolledRecord, setScrolledRecord] = useState(false);
```

```
  const scrolledEvent = scroll => {
    if (scroll?.contentOffset?.y > 0) {
      setScrolledRecord(true);
    } else {
      setScrolledRecord(false);
    }
  };
```

```
return   {scrolledRecord ? <ChatHeader item={userData} /> : null}
```

**In the about I have implemented the logic I think i am not correct**

Answer (score 0):

```
const useOnTop = () => {
 const [onTop, setOnTop] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
     if (window.scrollY === 0) {
        setOnTop(true);
    } else {
        setOnTop(false);
    }
  }, [window.scrollY]);

  return onTop;
}
```

and use it as follows

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const isOnTop = useOnTop();

    <>
      isOnTop && <MyOtherComponent />
    </>
}
```

Comment: Thank You For your time but this is not what I am looking for. you will get a higher number when you scrolled to the top like 100,200 or might be 20,000 when the user scrolls to the top, not 0.

Comment: change the `===` to `>==`

Comment: wait i have got the solution. I will post later